# Alias a remote branch localy

Tags: git

I'm working with a repo that has no `master` branch, but several `vX.Y` branches. I'll always be using let's say the `v1.2` as my remote branch. 
I'm used to refer to the remote branch as master and have a lot of alias to do things like :

```
alias grhm="git reset --hard origin/master"
```

and I would like to keep them unchanged, as this happens

Is there a way for me to refer to the `origin/v1.2` branch as `origin/master`? 
Can this be achieved with some entry in the `.git/config` file or something of the sort, so that I can keep working on other repos too with the same shell environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You can, but I think it's unwise.  You'll also have to be careful when pushing.  Consider rewiring your habits a bit and/or using `@{upstream}` or similar in your aliases.

#### Long

There is a way to do just what you want, but it's klunky and inflexible.  You will have to hand-maintain your `.git/config` file for this particular repository, updating it every time the set of branch names you wish to rename changes in any way.

When you run `git fetch` (you do use `git fetch` and not `git pull`, I hope :-) ... if you use `git pull` you will have more issues here), your Git uses the URL stored under the name of the remote—`origin`, in this case—to contact some other Git.  The other Git has branches, which would normally be named `master` and `develop` and so on, but someone has a quirky sense of names and/or humor and has used `v1.2` instead.  (This is much more suitable as a *tag* name than as a branch name.)

In any case, your `git fetch` gets a list of branches from *their* Git, and brings over any commits they have that you don't, using the raw commit hash IDs to achieve this.  The commits bring with them any files necessary.  Technically, Git just transfers *objects*, including commit, *tree*, and *blob* objects, to get everything.  In any case now that you have the commits, you have everything you need, except for one part: the *names*.

Your `git fetch` now proceeds to *rename* all their branch names.  This renaming is controlled by another setting under your remote name:

```
$ cat .git/config
[snip]
[remote "origin"]
    url = <some url>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The `url` setting contains the URL we already mentioned.  It's this `fetch` line that controls the way the renaming of their branch-names happen, though: this particular (standard) `fetch` setting tells your Git: *match anything starting with `refs/heads/`, and rewrite it to a string starting with `refs/remotes/origin/`*.  The first `*` is the "match anything" part and the second one tells Git to re-insert what was matched.

But you don't want to change `refs/heads/master` to `refs/remotes/origin/master` and `refs/heads/v1.2` to `refs/remotes/origin/v1.2`.  You want to, specifically, change `refs/heads/v1.2` (as seen on their Git) to `refs/remotes/origin/master` (to store in your Git repository).  Fortunately, you don't *have* to use `*` to match everything—you can list each name, one at a time:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = <some url>
    fetch = +refs/heads/v1.2:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/mr_t:refs/remotes/origin/i_pity_the_fool
```

and so on.  Each of these *refspecs* begins with a plus sign—this sets the "force" flag, so that your Git will overwrite *your* reference using *their* newly-fetched value even if that's not a fast-forward operation—and then lists *their* branch name, a colon to separate their name from your name, and then lists *your* name, in your `refs/remotes/origin/` name-space.  Since you're not using the `*` match, you *must* list *every* branch you wish to copy from them, and provide a unique name in your side.

**Note that these fetch refspecs have no effect on push operations.**  If you intend to push something from your `master` to their `v1.2`, you will have to run `git push origin master:v1.2`.  You can only set one *upstream* name for each branch; you'll need to use the renamed `origin/master` name, which is of course *not* the actual name over on `origin`.  With `push.default` configured to `simple` (as it is in Git 2.0 and later), if your branch name doesn't match their branch name—which it won't—you'll have to spell out all your push commands.